# Webscraping in Selenium on loops first Row and Pagination problem

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, pagination

I'm trying to scrape a Javascript page with selenium but I ran into some trouble. I'm trying to do for loop through all rows and then extract the table data from these rows. It's this site: https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/vzezR/4/

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/vzezR/4/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('G:/Python Projects/venv/Lib/site-packages/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

partyData = (driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr'))
print(partyData)

for item in partyData:
    party = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//td')
    party_leader = driver.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody//td[2]').text
    print (party, party_leader)
```

Expected output:

```
Rutte, M.
Kaag, S.
etc.
```

Output I've got:

```
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
Rutte, M.
```

Also, I'm trying to scrape all 159 pages but since the URL doesn't change and nothing changes in the network tab too. Any suggestions on how to tackle this? I was thinking of using GUI to let Python 'Click' the next page!

Let me know what you guys think! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use item. instead of driver. If you wanna xpath from an element.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to just parse the table that's embedded in json format in the script tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/vzezR/4/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
scripts = [script for script in scripts if script.string != None]
for script in scripts:
    if 'JSON.parse' in script.string:
        jsonStr = script.string.split('JSON.parse(',1)[-1]
        count=1
        while True and count < 50:
            try:
                jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(')',1)[0]
                jsonStr = json.loads(jsonStr)
                jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
                break
            except:
                count += 1
rows = []
for idx, line in enumerate(jsonData['data']['chartData'].splitlines()):
    if idx == 0:
        cols = line.split('\t')
        continue
    row = line.split('\t')
    rows.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                  Partij                   Naam Totaal Positie op kieslijst
0                 50PLUS         den Haan, N.L.  80533                    1
1                 50PLUS            Brood, R.G.   2581                    2
2                 50PLUS    Verkoelen, P.J.H.D.   4890                    3
3                 50PLUS          Nijkamp, M.O.    678                    4
4                 50PLUS  van Tilborg, H.C.A.M.   1446                    5
                 ...                    ...    ...                  ...
1576  Wij zijn Nederland          Schäfer, G.F.     19                    6
1577  Wij zijn Nederland           Mulder, P.J.     15                    8
1578  Wij zijn Nederland           Gilles, A.J.     14                    9
1579  Wij zijn Nederland         Hensen, Y.W.J.     72                   10
1580  Wij zijn Nederland           de Vries, D.     37                   11

[1581 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got the following when I tried to run your script:

line 49, in <module>
    for idx, line in enumerate(jsonData['data']['chartData'].splitlines()):
NameError: name 'jsonData' is not defined

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Means you’re not getting the same response in the request as me. I’ll look into it tomorrow, but first thing I’d try is add headers parameter with user agent to the request

Comment: Try using this url https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/vzezR/6/ within the script instead of what is currently used there. When you navigate to the url in your question manually, it automatically leads to the one I just pasted here @Jorginton.

Comment: Not sure why SIM gets a different url. First thing I’d try if I were you is as the user agent in the headers parameter and see if that works. Others ya, might need to find why that url is different or dynamic.

Comment: @Jorginton, I made slight edit. Give it a try now.